# How to add an integral primary key to a table created with SELECT INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 and am creating a table in the following way:

```
SELECT x, y
INTO CampRegistration
FROM tableA

UNION

SELECT x, y
FROM tableB
```

x and y are not primary keys. I wish for the `CampRegistration` table to have an additional column that is an integral surrogate primary key ie. something like an `IDENTITY`.

How can I do this, either by modifying the `SELECT INTO` or adding and populating the column afterwards?

Comment: create a sequence and also select from that.

Comment: Then why not create the `CampRegistration` table first with an `IDENTITY` column and just `INSERT` into it instead of `SELECT INTO`? It isn't clear why you want to use `SELECT INTO` here.

Comment: @Pondlife Convenince I suppose. The real query has many columns.

Comment: @CHS but how often are you doing this that knowing your table structure in advance is such a burden?

Comment: @Aaron I don't disagree. I just noticed that in this given situation I didn't know how to populate a new PK column to an existing table and wanted to know how to do it.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning the [`IDENTITY()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189838.aspx) here, which is intended for exactly this use case. Although in your specific example you can't use it because of the `UNION`.

Comment: @Pondlife - Yes you can. Just need to put the `UNION` in a derived table or CTE.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, that's true, what I should have said was that it can't be added directly to the OP's existing query. It's obviously possible if you re-write it, as you showed.

Comment: @Pondlife - Well the OP doesn't say they are not able to rewrite the query. In fact they specifically include the possibility of modifying it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other answers add the row number but don't make it a key and also don't help when you want to add a new registration. Here is how, after you've run your SELECT INTO, you can add an IDENTITY column and make it the key:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.CampRegistration
  ADD RegistrationID INT IDENTITY(1,1);

ALTER TABLE dbo.CampRegistration 
  ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CampRegistration
  PRIMARY KEY (RegistrationID);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`IDENTITY` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189838.aspx) to add a column with the `IDENTITY` property directly.

```
;WITH T
     AS (SELECT x,
                y
         FROM   tableA
         UNION
         SELECT x,
                y
         FROM   tableB)
SELECT IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) AS Id,
       x,
       y
INTO   CampRegistration
FROM   T
```

You would still need to add the PK constraint afterwards though which would add an additional unnecessary sort operation when the heap gets converted to a clustered index. The most efficient way would be to `CREATE` the table

```
SELECT TOP (0) IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) AS Id,
               x,
               y
INTO   CampRegistration
FROM   tableA
```

Then add the clustered primary key whilst the table is still empty.

Then insert into the table. SQL Server realizes that the `IDENTITY` will be in clustered index order and doesn't bother sorting them.

Answer (score 3):

Use window function to create the column on the fly.

```
SELECT Row_Number() Over (Order By x,y) As ID, x, y
INTO CampRegistration
FROM tableA
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you've got a UNION you'll need to use either a CTE or an Inline view.

e.g.

```
SELECT Row_Number() Over (order by x,y) rn, x,y
INTO CampRegistration
FROM
(
SELECT x, y
FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT x, y
FROM tableB
) as t
```

Answer (score 2):

how about using `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT x, y, ROW_NUMBER()
INTO CampRegistration
....
```

- [TSQL ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: ROW_NUMBER requires an over clause, and how would the numbering work across the union?